# Pass a non encoded string into a URL - Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, hubspot

I am using this script to pass data from a form into a URL

Problem: the email is passed encoded and a %40 is added instead of the `@`

- Any way to pass a non-encoded URL? I would like to pass the full email into the URL.

I need the full email because I use it then to populate a hidden field in a Typeform form.

Thanks a lot for your help :)

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="//js.hsforms.net/forms/v2-legacy.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="//js.hsforms.net/forms/v2.js"></script>
<script>
  hbspt.forms.create({
    portalId: "[PORTAL ID]",
    formId: "[FORM ID]"
  });
  // add custom script after it
  var array = [];
  window.addEventListener('message', event => {
    // in the onFormSubmit global form event, grab the data and push it to the above array
    if(event.data.type === 'hsFormCallback' && event.data.eventName === 'onFormSubmit') {
      let vars = ['firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'phone', 'hs_language'];
      let len = vars.length;
      for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        for (j in event.data.data) {
          if (event.data.data[j]["name"] == vars[i]) {
            let object = {
              name: '',
              value: ''
            };
            object.name = vars[i];
            object.value = event.data.data[j]["value"];
            array.push(object);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    // after the form has submitted and data sent to Hubspot, get the data from the array and then redirect the page, adding the data to the URL
    if(event.data.type === 'hsFormCallback' && event.data.eventName === 'onFormSubmitted') {
      var firstname = array[0].value
      var lastname = array[1].value
      var email = array[2].value
      var phone = array[3].value
      var lang = array[4].value
      window.location = "[URL TO REDIRECT TO HERE]?firstName=" + encodeURIComponent( firstname ) +"&lastName=" + encodeURIComponent( lastname ) +"&email=" + encodeURIComponent( email ) + "&phone=" + encodeURIComponent( phone ) + "&language=" + encodeURIComponent( lang );
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: This is a non-problem because you can simply run the value through `decodeURIComponent()` to get the original string

Comment: thanks, Chris, the decoded value should appear into the URL of the page that a contact is pointed to when they click `submit` - What is happening now is that the new URL has the encoded value there - Do you know how I can do that?

Comment: When you compose the URL, replace `encodeURIComponent( email )` with `email`

Comment: Note that I have no idea what the point of any of this is, or why anyone would care whether it says `@` or `%40` inside a long URL with a bunch of params. There's also a chance this is a massive [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/) but there's simply not enough information here to give a meaningful answer. Please try and clarify what the actual goal is here.

Comment: thanks Chris, I tried to replace  `encodeURIComponent( email )` with `email` but the result is the same!

Comment: The purpose is this:
- when someone submits a form on the first page there is a redirect to a new page, with another form and the URL of this page will looks like this www.testurl.com?firstname=ri_iu&email=test%40gmail.com and all the other parameters that you see in the script. I then have a Typeform in this page where all the values are passed automatically into the Typeform fields and from there I put the values un Hubspot. The problem is that the email has that coded part!

Comment: Ok, so it doesn't really matter that the email is encoded in the URL, as long as it ends up in its original form in the form? How are you feeding the URL params into the typeform code?

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for getting back to me. I have tested it out and Typeform has a direct decoder that fills the form with the @ directly. But I see your point here, I could have decoded before injecting in the form. I think that the main takeaway here is that is not possible to decode that @ into the URL directly. Thanks a ton for your help!